# How can "Best view for 2D Android game" be salvaged?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm posting this thread at the request of the asker of this question:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/best-view-for-2d-android-game-in-xamarin

The asker cannot post this his- or her-self due to the pointless and new-user-hostile reputation limits on participating in meta.

What can be done to salvage this question and make it on-topic and appropriate for this site?

Answer (score 2):

I think the below, while not doing the best at capturing the original intent, would change the question into something generally useful.

> What capabilities do more standard views typically used in game
>   development (SurfaceView or TextureView) provide beyond the WebView?
>   And is it worth incorporating these more complicated views into a game
>   that is only as complicated as the example game?

Part 1 can be answered based on technical knowledge and part 2 is good subjective in my opinion due to the below bullet points being hit.

- Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions.
- Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
- Great subjective questions are more than just mindless social fun.

I don't believe the engine part can incorporated without making the question too broad in scope or opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this question is off-topic because it asks "what would you recommend" of three possible technologies, which categorizes it as a "which technology" question.

---

I do think there's some potential to the topic, but I'm struggling to see how to phrase it. The (good) bit of the question is the part about using a `WebView` (or not) for the display of the game. "Should I use a `WebView`?" is basically a yes-or-no question (the answer to which is, "it depends -- if it works perfectly for you, keep doing it").

Edited to be a question about a specific problem the asker encountered with a `WebView` (beyond it "being strange") and asking how to overcome that would fit, I think, but there's no evidence in the original post that there is anything "wrong" with the asker's game or it's performance at all.

I think the query about switching to a game engine, and the two bulleted queries about "what would you recommend" need to get edited about. But beyond that I don't know how to reshape the question to be useful to the OP and still fit.

---

I do see one possibility, though, but it's a massive edit that more-or-less discards the "view" aspects of the question entirely. The asker's problem seems be to centered around the "design paralysis" issue of being halfway through a functional implementation and encountering doubts about the accepted correctness of his or her approach. I can see a case being made for transforming this question into the softer, but possibly [good-subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) query "Should I start over halfway through a working game if I'm not doing something 'correctly?'" leaving the original `WebView` example can be left in as a motivating example.